# Create macro for insertion of inkscape figure with width as a variable

Tags: macros, inkscape

To input figures directly from Inkscape I write this in a figure environment

```
\centering
\def\svgwidth{0.5\columnwidth}
\input{name.pdf_tex}
```

However, I would like to be able to just use a macro instead where the desired width is a variable, but I'm not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\newcommand\myimg[2]{%
\centering
\def\svgwidth{#1}%
\input{#2}}



\myimg{0.5\columnwidth}{name.pdf_tex}
```